# Prestashop webservice API didn't work

Tags: php, web-services, api, prestashop

I has been installed pastershop version prestashop_1.5.4.1. My site is host on localhost like **"localhost/myprestashop"**. When I read [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/720902/CRUD%20Tutorial%20EN.pdf) that calling prestashop webservice, it's pretty easy. But, when I call like that **"localhost/myprestashop/api"**, it's didn't work. I didn't see any xml result. I see "Not Found" Message at below.

[image]

I already enabled webservice and generate key. But, it's didn't work. Please point out me what kinds of problem in here. Webservice generate image is here.

[image]

Comment: Do you test with other web browsers?

Comment: Yes, test with chrome and Firefox!

Answer (score 3):

Test this urls in your browser:

`http://keyapi@localhost/api/customers`  ==> Replace keyapi string for your key api.

or

```
http://localhost/myprestashop/i/categories/5
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the url rewrite on your hosting and on your PrestaShop (in your SEO tab). That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pls try the following
You need to pass the key like explained in our documentation as  localhost/yourshop.com/api/?ws_key=YOUR_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have Webservice enabled under Advance Parameters->Webservice, then under the configuration section.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the rewrite module of the apache. Check if you have this module installed. Once you check this, you have to modify your configuration file of Apache (httpd in Windows, apache2.conf in Ubuntu) and replace the AllowOverride properties like this:

```
<directory />
Options All
AllowOverride All /*Put All instead of None*/
</directory>

<directory /directory/of/localhost>
Options All
AllowOverride All /*Put All instead of None*/
</directory>
```

Restart the Apache service and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several step to you have check,

1. check the rewrite_module enable, if it is disabled enable it.
   you can check whether the module is enabled or not run this code creating a PHP file

> ```
> <?php
> print_r(apache_get_modules());
> ?>
> ```

if you got more details without error, it seems already enabled

2. if you using existing project, Go to Prestashop and again create new another key and try again,